# SQL overwriting data

Tags: mysql, sql, overwrite

I'm trying to learn SQL and using MySQL and I'm just fooling around with it as a hobby. However, I found that in trying to manipulate the data I'm using, a lot of the time I end up overwriting some important information in my records, and I am unable to just ctrl-z this information back.

What are some safety tips when working with SQL that will help me from losing this information. Example, should I always keep a backup copy of all my tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always prefer writing your SQL queries in [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

> BEGIN and BEGIN WORK are supported as aliases of START TRANSACTION for
>   initiating a transaction. START TRANSACTION is standard SQL syntax and
>   is the recommended way to start an ad-hoc transaction.

The advantage of writing your code in transaction is you can rollback your transaction when  you want.

> Each transaction is stored in the binary log in one chunk, upon
>   COMMIT. Transactions that are rolled back are not logged.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into it now. I'll be able to use the rollback command presumably?

Comment: Yes..this is one of the way through which you can achive  what you want. :)

Comment: @JoeDanger:- I dont know who has downvoted for me but this is indeed what you were looking for. :)

Comment: Yeah. I understand. My question appears to have been down voted several times as well.

Comment: I also needed to change my table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB for START TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK to work. Do you know why this is?

Comment: **Because InnoDB is a transaction-safe (ACID compliant) storage engine for MySQL that has commit, rollback, and crash-recovery capabilities to protect user data. :)**

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Transactions allow you to Rollback certain blocks of code when something goes wrong during the execution.

Comment: Thanks Lourens, great reference!